# JRuby - Writing to a file using a ruby script embedded in Java

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

Newbie with Ruby.

I want to embed in Java, a Ruby script which process some file and then writes it into a different file.

I am invoking the script using the following code

`ruby = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
Object result = ruby.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE,<absolutepathtofile>);`

JRuby however, instead of writing to the file, returns the out put of the script (i.e. - the contents of the new file) in the result object instead of writing it to the file.

The ruby script when executed independently works fine.

Any idea how I can make the script write to the file directly?

Comment: why do you use ScriptContainer and a ruby script instead of just calling that script via the command-line?

Comment: That was dumb of me :(